# How to store button tags in a variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have 5 buttons representing cities, I have assigned them `tags` via `Attribute Inspector` as follows, `CityA as 0,.......CityE as 4`.

Is there a way I can store these tags into a variable `cityTag` and make sure that if none of button is pressed while saving, I can send a message `"Please select a city"`

I created an `action` with multiple buttons, but I have no idea how to create a `variable` and assign `tags` to it.

Comment: You can use `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are adding tags via the attribute inspector, you can access the tapped button's tag via `sender.tag` property!

Initially create an `NSMutableArray` (that will hold a the tags of all buttons pressed) but will obviously be empty at the start! You can access the tag with the `sender.tag` property in the `IBAction`. If your `NSMutableArray` doesn't contain a tag when you try to save, you can show the alert.

Answer (score 2):

For better readability of code yourcould define an `Enum` for that case which represents the name and tag as well :

for example:

```
enum City: Int {
    case .cityA,
    case .cityB,
    case .cityC
}
```

You can store them in an `Array`:

```
var cities: [City] = []
```

To set a city:

```
if let cityA: City = City(rawValue: button.tag) {
    cities.append(cityA)
}
```

To read the `Int` value:

```
let rawValue: Int = cityA.rawValue
```

Comment: I am trying to store tag value in model.Can the value of cities variable be stored in an attribute of type integer in core data.

Comment: You could have a private property from type `NSNumber` which holds the raw value  and write an extension on your `CoreData` model to map that value to the `City` enum through his getter and setter.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise `citytag = -1`. Change the value of citytag when you press a button like `citytag = sender.tag` and keep a check if `citytag == -1` then send a message `please select a city` else `selected city is ###`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
func checkbuttons -> BOOL {

   var countBtn = 0

   for view in self.view.subviews as [UIView] 
   {
       if let btn = view as? UIButton
       {
         if btn.isSelected
         {
           countBtn = countBtn + 1
         }
      }
   }
   if(countBtn > 0)
   {
      return true
   }
   else 
   {
      return false
   }
}
```

On basis of return you will know button selected or not.
Hope it will help you